# Not Receiving Logs From Splunk Forwarder or Syslog-ng what could be the issue

Tags: logging, splunk, syslog, syslog-ng

I have Splunk setup, and it establishes connection with syslog and splunk universal forwarder from a remote server:

[image: Splunk setup and establishes connection with syslog and splunk universal forwarder]

I have syslog-ng setup as follows:
[image: Syslog source and destination]

[image: Syslog log output]

You can see the connections established
[image: connections from syslog source of logs and forwarder]

This is the inputs.conf for the splunk universal forwarder:
[image]

But still no data is being received by splunk:
[image]

Am I missing something? And how would I go about troubleshooting the issue and fixing it?

Comment: That inputs.conf stanza should have `index` and `sourcetype` settings.  Also, "whitlist" should be "whitelist".  That won't solve the problem, however.

Comment: likely a good question - but belongs on Server Fault, not Stack Overflow